# Conjugaison pour des équipes de deux personnes (Vous et Nous)

Tags: conjugaison

Quand j'écris "Vous" désignant une équipe de 2 personnes contre "Nous", l'autre équipe de 2,
les verbes s'accordent-ils au singulier ou au pluriel ?

> Après 11 parties, Vous l'emportent 6 à 5, il faudra donc une autre rencontre pour que Nous se vengent.

Comment: Déjà, je corrige la citation qui doit être « Après 11 parties, vous l’emportâtes 6 à 5, il faudra donc une autre rencontre pour que nous nous vengions.

Comment: Ou la version plus moderne: "Après 11 parties, vous l'emportez 6 à 5, il faudra donc une autre rencontre pour que nous nous vengions."

Comment: Moins académique : "Après 11 parties, vous l’avez emporté 6 à 5, il faudra donc une autre rencontre pour que nous nous vengions (*pour qu'on se venge*)."

Comment: Bonjour, merci pour cette réponse mais dans le sens que je souhaite utiliser la phrase Nous et Vous ne sont pas la 1ère et 2ème personne du pluriel mais le nom des équipes... là est la "subtilité" de mon interrogation ! Merci de votre retour. cordialement. Jean-Paul

Comment: Si il s'agit de noms propres, alors je pense que je mettrais des guillemets pour marquer la distinction (au moins dans les premières phrases, et tout le temps si le texte utilisé également les "nous" et "vous" normalement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si « Vous » et « Nous » sont carrément et vraiment les noms des deux équipes comme vous dites en haut (et pas « Les Vous » ni « Les Nous »), moi je dirais qu’il faut le singulier, même si ça fait louche en le disant et l'entendant:

> Vous a gagné, les doigts dans le nez. Nous a perdu, les doigts dans le [Q] !

Comment: Tiens, j'ai toujours entendu « les doigts *dans* le nez », ou ailleurs.

Comment: Vous avez raison, @StéphaneGimenez . Je ne l’ai pas entendue ni chantée depuis l’été glorieux de 1998 et j’en avais perdu un bout effectivement (mais les paroles de « La Tribu de Dana », j’en souviens bien de cet été-là, par contre).  Je viens de la rédiger car je trouve que ma si belle réponse mérite la perfection !

Answer (score 3):

On accordera selon le nom de l'équipe :

*L'Olympique de Marseille a gagné.* (singulier) et *Les marseillais ont gagné.* (pluriel) sont tous les deux corrects.

Je dirais qu'il est plus naturel d'utiliser le pluriel car on aime mettre l'accent sur les joueurs.

Answer (score 1):

Au pluriel. Le pluriel en français est définit comme un groupe d’au moins deux personnes ou plus.

Il n’éxiste pas de pronoms personnels au [duel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel_(grammaire)) en français comme cela peut être le cas en arabe, en grec ancien ou en slovène.

Answer (score 1):

J'emploierais le singulier parce c'est *une équipe* qui gagne et *une autre* qui perd.

> Après 11 parties, [l'équipe] « Vous » l'emporte 6 à 5, il faudra donc une autre rencontre pour que [l'équipe] « Nous » se venge.